# Consulta que retorna se o filho herdou o sobrenome do pai e/ou da mãe

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um cenário que preciso classificar meus registros onde:

**O filho herdou o sobrenome do pai e/ou de sua mãe?**

Observe na imagem que, se um dos sobrenomes do filho existir no nome do pai o campo `PAI?` recebe verdadeiro. Da mesma forma para a o campo `MAE?`.

[image: planilha]

Construção do cenário

```
CREATE TABLE USUARIOS
    (CODIGO INT IDENTITY,
     NOME VARCHAR(255),
     MAE VARCHAR(255),
     PAI VARCHAR(255)
    )
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_CODIGO ON USUARIOS (CODIGO);
CREATE INDEX NOME ON USUARIOS (NOME, CODIGO);
CREATE INDEX MAE ON USUARIOS (MAE, CODIGO) INCLUDE(NOME);
CREATE INDEX PAI ON USUARIOS (PAI, CODIGO) INCLUDE(NOME);

GO

INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('ADRIANA ARAUJO DIAS','JOAO WILSON ARAUJO','JOSELIA PEREIRA ARAUJO')
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('NICOLAS PEDRO SILVA','SERGIO LUIZ SILVA JUNIOR','THAIS BATISTA DOS SANTOS SILVA')
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('CARLOS JOSE DOS SANTOS ANJO','ACACIO APARECIDO ANJO DA SILVA','JULIANA ARAUJO DOS SANTOS ANJO')
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('NICOLAY RIBEIRO DANTAS','RICARDO VICENTE RIBEIRO','JOZEILDA LUIS ENCARNACAO')
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('MARIA DA SILVA MATTOS','FRANKLIN DE OLIVEIRA','BRUNA CATARINA DA SILVA MATTOS')
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('CREUSA MARIA MORAES','GELSON DO ESPIRITO SANTO','FATIMA APARECIDA DOS SANTOS')
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('DAVID BRADAO BORGES','EMERSON DOS SANTOS BORGES','DAYANE EVANGELISTA ACACIO BORGES')
INSERT INTO USUARIOS (NOME, MAE, PAI) VALUES('LUIZ ADAO SANTOS DA SILVA','WESLEY GONCALVES SILVA','IZABEL BRANDAO DA SILVA')

GO

SELECT CODIGO, NOME, PAI, MAE,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USUARIOS T1
         WHERE T1.CODIGO = TAB.CODIGO AND
               CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(NOME, CHARINDEX(' ', NOME)+1, CHARINDEX(' ', NOME, CHARINDEX(' ', NOME)+1) - CHARINDEX(' ', NOME)-1), PAI) > 0  --FUNCIONA PARA O PRIMEIRO SOBRENOME (PAI)
         ) AS [PAI?],
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USUARIOS T1
         WHERE T1.CODIGO = TAB.CODIGO AND
               CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(NOME, CHARINDEX(' ', NOME)+1, CHARINDEX(' ', NOME, CHARINDEX(' ', NOME)+1) - CHARINDEX(' ', NOME)-1), MAE) > 0  --FUNCIONA PARA O PRIMEIRO SOBRENOME (MÃE)
        ) AS [MAE?]
FROM USUARIOS TAB
```

> Até onde cheguei, com a consulta acima, consigo pelo menos verificar
>   com o primeiro sobrenome, mas, como fazer nesta query para verificar
>   todos os sobrenomes?

*Obs: Os nomes que apresentei são fictícios. Não considerar se ao acaso coincidirem com pessoas reais.*

Comment: Talvez utilizando o recurso do Full-Text Search, seja mais pratico

Comment: Caso alguém queira testar, [aqui tem o fiddle online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00c3a/1) da pergunta.

Comment: @Randrade Aqui no serviço não tenho acesso a este site, mas muito obrigado, ajudará aos demais.

Comment: @ismael você tem controle sobre o banco de dados ou você utiliza alguma hospedagem compartilhada?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida Total controle.

Comment: @ismael de noite vou escrever uma ou algumas soluções para o seu problema

Comment: @ismael: Já deve ter percebido que é necessário que se tenha o nome de solteira da mãe e, no caso de filha, se casada, o nome de solteira dela.

Comment: Sim @JoséDiz, mas neste caso, apenas quero saber se contém ou não. Futuramente irei aprofundar neste conceito, a partir desta.

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida Como será a solução com Full-Text? Será tão simples como a que o Randrade postou? Será que tem um desempenho melhor?

Comment: Criei uma solução utilizando CLR, que o desempenho fica melhor q utilizando XML, daqui a pouco posto aqui explicando como fazer isso

Comment: @Ismael postei a solução caso tenha alguma dificuldade pode me informar que eu detalho mais o processo

Comment: @Ismael as soluções apresentadas te atenderam ou você precisa de mais algumas?

Comment: Oi @JefersonAlmeida, estou focado em outro projeto neste momento e ainda não pude ver com atenção este cenário, embora sua solução tb tenha funcionado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma boa maneira de se resolver isso é utilizando o [CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx), com ele vamos criar uma função em .Net para rodar diretamente no banco de dados.

Primeiro, precisamos criar um novo projeto no Visual Studio do tipo **SQL Server Database Project**, após isso você vai ter que adicionar um novo item do tipo **SQL CLR C# User Defined Function**, também será necessário adicionar nas references o **System.Core**, pois utilizaremos funções dela.

Isso te possibilitará a criar um função em C# para ser utilizada internamente pelo SQL Server, a função que você irá criar para comprar os sobrenomes será dessa forma:

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlBoolean ComparaSobrenome(string nome1, string nome2)
    {
        if (nome1 == null || nome2 == null)
            return new SqlBoolean(false);

        //Ignora o priemiro nome da pessoa na comparação, caso queira incluir ele retirar .Skip(1).ToArray()
        var nome1Array = nome1.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToArray();
        var nome2Array = nome2.Split(' ').Skip(1).ToArray();

        if (nome1Array.Length == 0 || nome2Array.Length == 0)
            return new SqlBoolean(false);

        foreach (var n1 in nome1Array)
        {
            foreach (var n2 in nome2Array)
            {
                if (ContainsInsensitive(n1, n2))
                {
                    return new SqlBoolean(true);
                }
            }
        }

        return new SqlBoolean(false);
    }

    public static bool ContainsInsensitive(string source, string search)
    {
        return string.Compare(source, search, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0;
    }
}
```

Isso vai criar uma função chamada `ComparaSobrenome` que irá aceitar duas *strings* como parâmetro e retornar um *boolean*. Note que na minha comparação eu estou ignorando o *Case Sensitive* e o *Acento Sensitive*, além disso eu estou ignorando a primeira parte do nome nas comparações, pois você informou que só quer comprar os sobrenomes das pessoas.

Após ter feito isso vai ser necessario dar um Build no seu projeto, para que ele gere crie a DLL disso.

Indo para a parte do Banco de Dados agora.

No Sql Server vai ser necessário rodar os seguintes comandos para que seja habilitado a utilização de CLR, que por padrão vem desabilitado.

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Depois disso você vai precissar instalar a DLL no seu banco, selecione o banco que você deseja que sua função seja criado e execute o seguinte comando

```
Create Assembly ClrTeste from 'C:\ClrTeste\ClrTeste\bin\Debug\ClrTeste.dll' with Permission_set = SAFE
GO
```

Sendo que ClrTeste é o nome do Assembly que será criado e o caminho do from é onde está a DLL que foi gerada quando você deu um build no seu projeto.

Após a criação do Assembly vamos criar uma Function no banco que vai chamar esse Assembly.

```
Create Function ComparaSobrenome(@Nome nvarchar(max), @Nome2 nvarchar(max) )
RETURNS bit
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
    EXTERNAL NAME ClrTeste.UserDefinedFunctions.ComparaSobrenome;
GO
```

Após isso bata utiliza-la na sua query dessa forma:

```
SELECT NOME, MAE, PAI, dbo.ComparaSobrenome(NOME, MAE) AS SobrenomeMae, dbo.ComparaSobrenome(NOME, PAI) AS SobrenomePai
FROM USUARIOS
```

Comment: Um tutorial muito bem explicado. Assim que puder irei construir esse cenário e darei um *feedback* sobre o desempenho.

Comment: @Ismael qualquer duvida ou problema é só perguntar

Answer (score 7):

Você pode criar uma função para realizar o `split` dos dados e depois apenas fazer um `join` simples.

Um exemplo funcional seria isso:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Após isso, basta alterar a sua ``query`para utilizar a`function`, desta forma:

```
SELECT codigo, nome, pai, mae, 
(SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(nome, ' ') AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_XML(pai, ' ') AS b
    ON a.Item = b.Item
)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Pai?',
(SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(nome, ' ') AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings_XML(mae, ' ') AS b
    ON a.Item = b.Item
)
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Mae?'
FROM USUARIOS
```

[Veja o exemplo funcional no SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/872a61/1/0)

> Note que estou usando a abordagem com `XML`. Ela pode ser utilizada em ambiente controlado, mas não é muito aconselhado em produção, pois se você inserir algum illegal XML characters, ela pode explodir.

[Neste site](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) você pode ver diversos exemplos de como implementar outras funções, com CLR, XML, Numéros, CTE e Moden.

Acho interessante também você olhar estas perguntas:

- [How to compare two strings with same delimiter in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38029875/4843158)
- [In SQL Server, how to create while loop in select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19891594/4843158)

Comment: Ótima solução Randrade, funciona perfeitamente, porém, não está com um desempenho aceitável. Vou verificar os índices.

Comment: @Ismael Esse é um dos problemas de utilizar essa abordagem. Para ter um desempenho melhor, você pode utilizar CLR ao invés do XML. [Neste site que postei na resposta](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) possui um exemplo de como utilizar CLR.

Comment: Não tenho acesso a este site :( mas poderei verificar em casa.

Comment: @Ismael Eu postei desta forma pq outro usuário do site me disse que iria postar uma resposta sobre CLR hoje para você, então preferi postar uma diferente.

Comment: Tudo bem Randrade, estou aqui estudando melhor `.query`. Levou 16min para analisar 347092 registros válidos. No plano de execução, os custos ficaram por conta do **XML Reader with XPath filter**.